# Database design for transactions and accounts

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I need a basic account/transaction system and have some trouble deciding on the database design for PostgreSQL.

- Users can have multiple accounts in different currencies
- Each account can have multiple transactions (income, expense)
- Two transactions can belong together (transfer), they need to be ignore for analytics of income and expenses.

```
accounts
--
id
user_id
currency_id
name
(balance, maybe as rolling sum to get the current balance)
```

What would be a good design for the transactions?
How do I group 2 transactions together (for transfers)?

```
transactions
--
id
account_id
datetime
amount
type (I for income, E for expenses, T for transfers)
```

or

```
transactions
--
id
account_from_id (null for income)
account_to_id (null for expense)
datetime
amount_from (null for income)
amount_to (null for income)
```

or add a `group` column and a `transaction_groups` table to pair transactions together?

**Update 1**

I added a `group_id` column to the first version.
Incomes are positive amounts, expenses are negative amounts and transfers have a group id.
So now I can easily aggregate the balance just by summing up all amounts for each account.

```
transactions
--
id
account_id
group_id
datetime
amount
```

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re how/why you are 1st stuck on what step among which steps following what published presentation of what design method/process given what? [ask] [Help] PS Putting words in scare quotes does not clarify the idiosyncratic meaning that you don't make clear by actually saying what you mean.

Comment: @philipxy For what it's worth, the first sentence of your comment is unintelligible. Your PS is similarly hard to decipher. Finally, putting things in quotes is not necessarily an attempt at using "scare quotes"; something is a "scare quote" if it is intended to be read with skepticism or doubt by the user. The usage of quotes here was more of an approximation by the OP due to not knowing an ideal, idiomatic word.

Comment: @TylerH The sentence is intelligible, I expect that you know exactly what it means, it is just unusual, and it is written that way for a reason, but I will think about a more usual sentence. The quotes were [scare quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes#Usage) & regardless the point was they were either in lieu of clear writing or didn't belong. My postscript is perfectly normal. We disagree. Thank you though.

Comment: @philipxy I can make a guess, at best, but I have a rather strong grasp of English. I don't think it's helpful to users if they have to spend significant effort trying to understand what you are saying from a syntactical perspective. And no, it is really _not_ intelligible, and no, they really _aren't_ scare quotes, just because you really want them to be (and, really, there is nothing wrong with them).  If you want comment advice to get through to users, I recommend writing more clearly and with better grammar (avoid multiple run-on sentences, for one).

Comment: @TylerH Again, we disagree on almost everything in your last comment but thanks.

Comment: What is your 1 specific question? What does your research show that is relevant to your question? What published DB design textbook/reference/presentation are you following? What is the design method? What are its steps? Where is the first place you are stuck? Why/how are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

For your proposed `transactions` table only the second is practical. A transfer requires both a `from` and a `to`. The second is the only one containing both. I would suggest a couple changes. First, only 1 amount column. Both `from` and `to` receive the same amount. Add a column for the transaction type (I for income, E for expenses, T for transfers) as you indicated. Then you can use the type code code to validate the proper to/from id(s) are supplied. Something like:

```
create table transactions( id               integer  generated always as identity
                                                     primary key  
                         , transaction_code text     check (transaction_code = any (array['T', 'E', 'I']))
                         , account_from_id  integer  references accounts(id) 
                                                     check (   (account_from_id is null and transaction_code = 'I')
                                                            or (account_from_id is not null and transaction_code <> 'I')
                                                           )
                         , account_to_id    integer  references accounts(id) 
                                                     check (   (account_to_id is null and transaction_code = 'E')
                                                            or (account_to_id is not null and transaction_code <> 'E')
                                                           )
                         , datetime         timestamp with time zone not null default current_timestamp
                         , amount           numeric(7,2)       
                         );
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I thought of two amount columns because if the accounts have different currencies and the exchange rate from the system does not fit the one the user needs, he can just type in both amounts.

Comment: Also it would be easier to sum up all the amounts to get the account balance (sum(amount_to) - sum(amount_from)), right? I edited my question and added a third option.